# Does 'will-change' or the translateZ() hack improve any performance on 'transition: height'

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am building an accordion with animated height on open/close, in which the content height is calculated via JS. I want to ensure the best performance, so I was thinking about forced hardware acceleration.

```
.accordion-item-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    will-change: transform;
}
```

In the Chrome Dev Tools I can see that the accordion-items are each getting a layer (because of the will-change and/or transform property), but will this result in any performance boost?
Or are transform, opacity and filter the only properties that can ever benefit from GPU rendering, as I understood here: http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/

Another question: Does 'will-change: height' do anything? It looks like it's valid (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), but it does NOT create a layer, I can observe in the dev tools.

Comment: The latest info that I have find is here https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/pull/330    If this is the current status, NO, will-change: height won't create a layer in Chrome. But notice that this is highly browser specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really `will-change` or `transform: translateZ()` will promote your element to it's own layer which get's send over to your GPU.
Have a look at https://csstriggers.com/. You should only animate `transform` and `opacity`. Any other properties cause repaint or layout recalculation even if you are using `will-change`.